# flutter_recaptcha_v2 depends on http ^0.12.0+1 and my_app depends on http ^0.13.1

Tags: android, flutter, android-studio, flutter-dependencies, flutter-web

I'm Using [flutter_recaptcha_v2](https://pub.dev/packages/flutter_recaptcha_v2) for verifying captcha in my app but Its conflicting with [http ^0.13.1](https://pub.dev/packages/http), It Says,

```
Because every version of flutter_recaptcha_v2 depends on http ^0.12.0+1 and my_app depends on http ^0.13.1, flutter_recaptcha_v2 is forbidden.
So, because my_app depends on flutter_recaptcha_v2 any, version solving failed.
pub finished with exit code 65
```

I'm not able to decrease my **http** package version because many other packages are depending on it.
Previously, I've fixed version solving problem and changed many packages with **http** package version to **http ^0.13.1**. What should I do to use **flutter_recaptcha_v2** without changing **http** package version.

Comment: You can not actually. You need to wait until the package is updated. Maybe create an issue regarding this.

Comment: Issue is created already and I also created one, but no response to previous issues and i think they are not maintaining the package.

Answer (score 0):

decrease the http version to 0.12.0+1

Comment: not possible, because there many other packages which depends on http version.

Comment: decrease them also ,try to find the best versions for all of them

Comment: I've already did this before to work all packages fine, and I got working http version http ^0.13.1, so I'll not decrease the http version, if I do, whole project will get messed.